# How to set filter stopband attenuation for a block in gnuradio companion?

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I would like to set the stopband attenuation value for a bandpass filter in GNU Radio Companion.
The standard Band Pass Filter block does not allow to set this parameter, but uses a default.

Does anybody know how this could be done?

I tried the following:

- searched for various filter blocks and filter tap calculator blocks in GNU Radio Companion: could not find any that allows to set this parameter, even though the underlying filter coefficient calculator functions have such input.
- created an Embedded Python Block and tried to use it to wrap the filter coefficient calculator (gnuradio.filter.optfir.complex_band_pass) that allows setting this parameter and the filter (gnuradio.filter.fft_filter_ccc) that uses the coefficients to do the filtering. Somehow the filter's work method cannot be called properly from the wrapper block's work method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to write an embedded block to use the Filter design tools GNU Radio brings – you can just use Python as the "taps" parameter of an existing FIR filter block (instead of just typing in your filter tap vector, e.g. `[1,2,3,4]`), i.e., add an "Import" block, where you `from gnuradio.filter import optfir`, and use `optfir.whatever(...)` as "Taps" parameter.

Other than that, GNU Radio's forte is not designing specialized filters, honestly :) I do recomment the excellent pyFDA; I'd install it locally using

```sh
python3 -m venv filter-design
source ./filter-design/bin/activate
pip3 install pyfda
pyfdax
```

and use it to design your favorite filter, if you don't need to re-design it programmatically on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Marcus!
The workaround I found involves using gnuradio.filter.optfir.complex_band_pass in a separate python script to design the required filter, extracting the filter coefficients and entering them for a FIR filter block (e.g. Decimating FIR Filter with decimation of 1) in gnuradio companion. A bit tedious if you need to change the filter, but works.

Comment: yes, as said in the first half of my answer, you don't have to do that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, sorry for hijacking the conversation, but I run into your name trying to make the GRC filter design tool work. I'm running into the " top_block_start_unlocked(self._impl, max_noutput_items)
ValueError: buffer_add_reader: nzero_preload must be >= 0" error and I see that you wrote this part of the code. I running GRC on a windows 10 PC.

Comment: the pyfda works great. Can you elaborate on how to make the filter parameters available to GRC filter blocks? I have very limited python experience.

Comment: I saved the calculated filter coefficients as a CSV file and used the Filter Taps Loader block which correctly got all the coefficients. But the frequency Xlating FIR Filter only gets the last pair of coefficients instead of all the vector. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @PanosKontogiannis then let's not hijack the conversation; open a question post instead, please?